# Settings Activity onCreate() not called

Tags: java, android, xml

On pressing Settings, I just get a plain whit screen, with the layout not drawn over, so I set breakpoints to check what was happening. The class gets called, but `onCreate()` doesn't get called.

Here's the code -

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.settings_toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_toolbar);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.content_frame, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        }
    }
}
```

And here's the layout file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/settings_toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of R.xml.preferences file? You sure it has stuff properly declared in it?

Comment: Use Protected Instead Of Public Before Calling onCreate().see if that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try use

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

instead of

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

Comment: Did the trick. Thanks. I'll have to wait a bit before I can accept your answer.

Comment: can you explain why the second one is never called ?

Answer (score 0):

You are overridding wrong method.

Use:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Take a look inside documentation of AppCompatActivity's protected methods:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#promethods

Answer (score 0):

As the answers posted by @Gabo and @NaiveBz, your own onCreate() function was incorrect.

Check out this page:
[Docs provided by developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}
```

There's only one Bundle parameter.